# Laravel merge logic

Tags: laravel, collections, merge, model, eloquent

In my case i need to use collections together. But also i need that model too. I decided to merge eloquents. Like this:

```
        $products = Product::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
        $sliders = Slider::orderBy('order', 'asc')->get();
        $news = News::orderBy('order', 'asc')->get();

        $collection = new ModelCollection();
        $result = $collection->merge($products)->merge($news)->merge($sliders)->sortByDesc('created_at');
        dd($result);
```

$products has 4 data, $slider also has 4 data, $news has 3 data. 
But i am allways get 4 data by sorting created_at. Why i can't get 11 data from the collection?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-merge

in this case there is no limit or rules.
in the interest of brevity i am trying to make an array with my selected models. If its a collection it keeps model. If its just an array also i need to add the model name for each data collections.

```
array(
Products > product1,product2,product3,product4
News > news1, news2, news3
Slider > slider1, slider2, slider3
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all collections in one array you can do by this,

```
$products = Product::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
$sliders = Slider::orderBy('order', 'asc')->get();
$news = News::orderBy('order', 'asc')->get();

$result = array();
$result['products'] = $products;
$result['sliders'] = $sliders;
$result['news'] = $news;
```

This will create collection `$result` like you want,

```
array(
products > product1,product2,product3,product4
news > news1, news2, news3
sliders > slider1, slider2, slider3
)
```

Hope this will help you. Comment if any doubts.

Comment: That worked. But why $collection = new Eloquent();
and $collection->merge($foo)->merge(.... 
doesn't worked?

Comment: Based on my experience, I think there is no method like `new Eloquent()` which can define new Eloquent. **Eloquent is simple ActiveRecord implementation for working with your database.** Eloquent itself is a method of laravel. So you can't create just new Eloquent as you have tried. Yes you can merge collection with other collection but for that you should have both collection with real data.

Comment: i mean when i said new Eloquent();
**use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection as ModelCollection;**
and **$collection = new ModelCollection;**
thats what i use. Its also working like i want. But its just not showing all the instances.

Comment: Yes, that's nice. But You have already queried your collections in `products`,`news` and `sliders`. So next thing you can do is work with your collection like in the answer. Do not try to make new ModelCollection or other things, these things will take more times to load and make your process little slower.

Comment: When you have already collections, the best way is to play with those collections and make results as desired. I hope you will understand this. And You can upvote my answer too as an appreciation. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. :)